# Get current dir in a class library

Tags: c#, json, wpf, windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm developing a C# library with .Net Framework 4.5.1 to use it in a Windows 8.1 desktop application.

Inside this library project I have a `JSON` file, and I want to load it. First, I have tried to get current directory with this:

```
string currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

But, I have test it and `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` is null.

Maybe, I can use a resource file instead of a JSON file.

This is the method:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    string currentDir = 
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

    string file = 
        Path.Combine(currentDir, cardsDir, cardsFile);

    string json =
        File.ReadAllText(file);

    Deck = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Card[]>(json);
}
```

Any idea? Is there a better approach? How can I get current dir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

this will return the current working directory of your application. now you can access any file relative to your application

```
string currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

Comment: I think that will yield that same results as his first line in `string currentDir`

Comment: Thanks, `Environment.CurrentDirectory` returns current directory.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, you have to take into account @Hagai Shahar answer, the way to go would be using **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory**

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention that `Environment.CurrentDirectory` **does not necessarily** return the directory that contains the application files.  It depends on where you started the application from.

For example, if the exe file is located at `C:\User\ProgramName\prog.exe` but you start the application from `cmd` like this:

```
C:\> C:\User\ProgramName\prog.exe
```

...the result of `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will be `C:\` and not `C:\User\ProgramName`.

Furthermore, it happens also in shortcuts:

[image: Application properties screen shot]

See the "Start In" property? If this is set it will become the result of `Environment.CurrentDirectory` because the application will be started from there.

Another solution is to get the location of the assembly which runs the application, something like this:

`typeof(Program).Assembly.Location`

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer something within your class library using paths relative to it because you library will be a .dll file, not a folder structure. What you can do is to set the file's `Copy if newer` property to `Copy always`. This way, your json will be copied to the debug folder, along with the project.

It means that your file will be placed in the `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` folder, which means that your `LoadData()` will work fine